# I am trying to find the quicksight formula for calculating 30 days hospital readmits

Tags: calculated-columns, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field, quicksight-embedding, aws-quicksight-assets

I am trying to find the quicksight formula for calculating 30 days hospital readmits.
Med_id,
MedName,
Admission_date
Discharge_date.

fyi*The data is being pulled from one source. there is no join

ifelse(Datedifff(('day', minover{discharge_date}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.